# Jest program for Array Out of bound exception

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am trying to study jest but since this concept is very new to me I am unable to solve this practice question. Can somebody help me to solve this and please add Comments so that I understand.

Consider the function

updateTask(index,update_task) that updates the task at given index in Tasks array.

. Write a test for the following scenario that throws an Array Out of Bounds Exceptio

. index is greater than Tasks array length.

**

```
Array: 
var tasks =[];
tasks =[{task_name: "task 1", status: "Open"},
{task_name:"Task 2", status:"closed"}];
```

**

Answer (score -1):

index.test.js:

```
enter code here:

const task = require("./tasks");
const updateTask = (index, update_task) => {
if(index > task.length){
 throw new Error("Array Out of Bounds Exception")
}else{
  task[index] = update_task;
}
}
test("Array Out of Bounds", () => {
  expect(updateTask).toThrow();
  expect(updateTask).toThrow(Error);
  expect(updateTask).toThrow("Array Out of Bounds Exception")
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).